# Странное поведение IE7 при подключении .htc библиотек

Tags: javascript, html, css

Обозреватель начинает мигать (подобного эффекта можно добиться зажав кнопку F5, то бишь обновлять каждую секунду) в конце концов браузер просто зависает. 
 Если быть точней, подключаю `csshover`. При использовании других библиотек например `pie` подобного эффекта не наблюдается. Скачивал разные версии библиотеки, одно и тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Выход: не зажимать "F5"

Comment: Я не зажимаю. Я имел ввиду что создается такое впечатление

Comment: Перестать мучатся с ИЕ, осознать что браузеру уже 10+ лет и будет вам счастье :)

Comment: это ие6 10+ лет, а ие7 2006 года выпуска и его нужно поддерживать

Comment: @JIOnOCTb я не пользовался этой библиотекой, может очень много идет обращений к ней? 

а лучше попробуйте обойтись без нее. Ведь даже PIE (который у вас не моргает) заметно замедляет работу и так не быстрого браузера.

Comment: ЛОЛ если ie7 2006ого года то каким макаром он мог идти в комплекте с windows xp 2001ого? Машину временеи уже изобрели? xD

Comment: да...подобные библиотеки сильно грузят. И как я понял проблема именно в огромном количестве запросов к библиотеке. А что поделать)) Заглушки не выход

Comment: @JIOnOCTb почитал, про этот htc. Зачем он тебе, что ты подсвечивать собираешься?

@AlexWindHope судя из Педивикии и http://evolutionofweb.appspot.com/ (классно сделано) IE7 появился 18 октября 2006года

Comment: @AlexWindHope Пакет обновлений 2 (Service Pack 2, SP2) (кодовое название «Springboard») был выпущен 6 августа 2004 года. SP2 добавил в Windows XP новые возможности, включая улучшенный файрволл; поддержку Wi-Fi с мастером настройки и Bluetooth, а также улучшения в Internet Explorer 6 — например, возможность блокировать «всплывающие» окна.

Answer (score 0):

Существуют другие браузеры, как ни странно, попробуйте разные. У меня стоят все, и свои сайты я тестирую во всех видах.

Comment: Все и везде работает. Кроме IE разумеется.